# Recover content of a directory when the block where directory file is located is corrupted?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

A user has a `Personal` folder in it's `/home/user` folder.
Bad sectors appeared on the hard drive. If I `vi` the `Personal` folder file it's empty and if I go into it and I do an `ls`, the system gets stuck for a while and finally nothing is displayed (just `.` and `..`).
So it seems like the sector where the `inode` of the `Personal` directory file is located, became corrupted.
The hard drive has other bad sectors, but most of the data can be recovered and I guess that most of the content of the `Personal` folder could be recovered too if I could access it.

As the directory file contains the list of the files within it, in such cases, is it possible to to recover the files inside this folder, or the files are lost ?

Comment: if you run `fsck` to repair the fs it should put the orphaned files and subdirs in `/lost+found` on the filesystem.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated because the faulty hard-drive is from a macbook (HFS), plugged into a linux box, and I didn't wanted to run `fsck` to avoid more damage, but i'll try this, thanks